# qml chartview becomes nullptr when sent to C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a data source containing multiple series of data (not known upfront).

I want to add a `LineSeries` to a qml `ChartView`, so I tried to 'hook' the C++ side to the qml like so:

```
// data source
...
Q_PROPERTY(QtCharts::QChartView *chart READ chart WRITE setChart NOTIFY chartChanged)
public slots:
void setChart(QtCharts::QChartView *newChart) {
  qDebug() << "received new chart to draw on:" << newChart;
}
```

And in the qml, I send the chart to C++ more or less like:

```
...
ChartView { id: chart
  ...
}
Component.onCompleted: { backend.setChart(chart) }
```

Now the `setChart` is called allright, but the type does not appear to match: the incoming chart pointer is null:

```
> received new chart to draw on:  QWidget(0x0)
```

Relaxing the input type to plain `QObject*` has shown me that the actual type of the incoming object is [`QtQuick::DeclarativeChart`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/chartsqml2/declarativechart.h.html).

How should I send the `chart` item to my C++ model?  (Or should I use a totally different approach?)

Comment: maybe there is a type problem between https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchartview.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html you are expecting a QWidget and QML gives you a QtQuickItem

Comment: Probably... should I go via the `QtQuickItem` then?

Comment: I think you need to change void setChart(QtCharts::QChartView *newChart) to void setChart(QQuickItem *newChart) and try things like http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html. i think  it's better if the C++ don't know the QML and the C++ send data to the QML via event

Comment: I guess you should change an application logic, not the function. The way you are trying to do that is wrong. Provide chart data through model or some proxy object from C++to QML, not back. Probably QML object has not corresponding C++ classes or they are private.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update chart axis and series you should send them into c++ and update them i wrote an example you can take a look i think it dose what you want .
On this example i converted c++ voice example from QWidget charts to QML chart but info in series are updating in c++ :
[QML chart updating in c++ Example](https://github.com/FONQRI/voice_realtime_show_case_qml)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem (I needed access to the chart in C++ to hide some markers on the chart legend).

I was able to get access to the chart by passing a pointer to an existing series on the chart to my C++ code.

```
void GraphHelper::hideLegends(QtCharts::QScatterSeries *series) {
    QtCharts::QChart *chart = series->chart();
    // do something with the chart...
}
```